# How to configure static nginx redirections for many sites?

Tags: redirect, nginx

There are hosting with nginx configured for many sites.
Now we want allow users to configure redirections. They look like:

```
/page/from.html /page/to.thml
... ...
```

Does it possible to say `nginx` to look into specified file for site and do redirection if request match?

**UPD**

Better solution be when `nginx` should not be required to restart.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this configuration in nginx default config file :

```
map $old_uri $redirects {
    example.com/def   example.com/abc;
    example.com/def   example.com/abc;
}
```

[Link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map)